# Berachah at the zoo?

Tags: blessing, animals

Should one say the Berachah of משנה הבריות when one goes to the zoo* and sees many animals one would never see outside the zoo? What if one actually sees animals that he has never seen before? Should he make multiple Berachoth?

<sub>*Substitute, as needed, "aquarium", "nature preserve", or any other institution that exists, at least in part, to allow visitors to see exotic animals they can't see elsewhere.</sub>

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21984/blessing-on-the-next-american-president#comment49995_21985

Comment: Why would a zoo be different than seeing the animal in their natural habitat? Are you asking if you should say it every time you visit the zoo?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1847

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43942/759

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34239&st=&pgnum=27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed one says the bracha

בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה' אֱלֹהֵינוּ מֶלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם מְשַׁנֵּה הַבְּרִיּוֹת

at the zoo.

Says [Revach](http://www.revach.net/halacha/tshuvos/Rav-Shlomo-Zalman-Auerbach-Bracha-At-The-Zoo-and-the-Aquarium/2442)

> The Shulchan Aruch ([OC 225:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.225.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) says that one make the bracha if
>   you see an elephant or monkey. Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach says that
>   you make this bracha not only on these two animals but any animals
>   that people see and are intrigued and amazed. **When visiting the
>   zoo says Rav Shlomo Zalman, you make the bracha once and have in mind
>   for all the animals.** However when going to an aquarium you do not need
>   to make the bracha since all the examples given by the gemara are for
>   land animals and not creatures of the sea.  (Aleihu Lo Yibol OC 168)

See also [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 60:13-14](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.60.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

[Halachipedia](http://For%20seeing%20a%20monkey%20or%20elephant%20for%20the%20first%20time%20one%20should%20make%20the%20Bracha%20of%20Meshaneh%20HaBriyot.%20However,%20if%20one%20sees%20another%20monkey%20or%20elephant,%20one%20can%20not%20make%20the%20Bracha%20again%20with%20Shem%20UMalchut,%20however,%20if%20it%20has%20been%2030%20days%20one%20can%20make%20the%20Bracha%20without%20Shem%20UMalchut.%20[2]%20It%E2%80%99s%20permissible%20to%20go%20to%20the%20zoo%20to%20see%20an%20elephant%20and%20monkey%20in%20order%20to%20make%20these%20Bracha.%20[3]) adds

> For seeing a monkey or elephant for the first time one should make the
>   Bracha of Meshaneh HaBriyot. However, if one sees another monkey or
>   elephant, one can not make the Bracha again with Shem UMalchut,
>   however, if it has been 30 days one can make the Bracha without Shem
>   UMalchut.
>
> It’s permissible to go to the zoo to see an elephant and monkey in
>   order to make this Bracha.

see [there](http://For%20seeing%20a%20monkey%20or%20elephant%20for%20the%20first%20time%20one%20should%20make%20the%20Bracha%20of%20Meshaneh%20HaBriyot.%20However,%20if%20one%20sees%20another%20monkey%20or%20elephant,%20one%20can%20not%20make%20the%20Bracha%20again%20with%20Shem%20UMalchut,%20however,%20if%20it%20has%20been%2030%20days%20one%20can%20make%20the%20Bracha%20without%20Shem%20UMalchut.%20[2]%20It%E2%80%99s%20permissible%20to%20go%20to%20the%20zoo%20to%20see%20an%20elephant%20and%20monkey%20in%20order%20to%20make%20these%20Bracha.%20[3]) for sources