# bracha when snorkeling/diving underwater and seeing a strange animal

Tags: halacha, blessing, water

There is a bracha said when seeing strange animals (presumably on land and/or in the air). If you are under water and see a wondrous sea creature, do you 'think' the bracha, or mouth it, or do you wait till you reemerge to speak it?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29334 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1847

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a teshuvah from Rav Shlomo Zalman Aurbach quoted [here](http://www.revach.net/halacha/tshuvos/Rav-Shlomo-Zalman-Auerbach-Bracha-At-The-Zoo-and-the-Aquarium/2442) which says that since the Gemara's examples of animals that we make the bracha on are land animals, we do not make it on sea creatures.

If one saw a land animal while submerged in water your question would still apply.

Comment: What about a sea creature that is a mammel and breaches the water often (like a whale)? Is Rav Aurbach saying one never says the bracha for a sea creature, or only it is not necessary to do so (especially when speech is impossible)?