# Beracha of משנה הבריות for a dead animal?

Tags: blessing, death, animals

Other questions, [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29334/berachah-at-the-zoo/86851#86851) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/why-do-you-make-a-bracha-on-seeing-a-monkey), discuss saying the beracha of משנה הבריות when seeing various animals.

Does the same apply if the animal is dead?*, **

Some examples where this can happen: 1) Seeing a dead beached whale, 2) seeing a particular dead animal at the zoo and, 3) going hunting with someone and only seeing the dead animal.

*I can think of similar/equivalent questions regarding various people that we say a beracha when seeing them

** At a stretch, perhaps this question can also include taxidermy

Answer (score 1):

see link below where he says that one would not make such a beracha on a dead or taxidermy animal.

https://tablet.otzar.org/#/b/647819/p/-1/t/1/fs/J0DKUUbCosVV9KtlltURAvAFYHNK3QUV7QpLe6t9mz56/start/15/end/40/c

Comment: The link doesn't work for me.

Comment: You may have to make an account and log in.

Comment: Can you summarise the answer please?